# Does $(y-x^2)^k$ for some natural number $k$ lie in the ideal $(x-1,y-1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The parabola $$y-x^2=0$$ passes through (1,1). So, by Nullstellensatz, I think $$y-x^2$$ raised to some natural number should lie in the ideal $$(x-1,y-1)$$ because this is the ideal whose corresponding algebraic set is $$(1,1)$$. But I am unable get this natural number. Can someone help? Or have I not understood something right?

Answer (score 2):

You have $(y-x^2)\subset(x-1,y-1)$ because
$$y-x^2=(y-1)-(x-1)(x+1).$$

Comment: Why is $$(y-1)-(x-1)(x+1) \in (x-1,y-1)$$?

Comment: What is your definition of $(x-1,y-1)$? It should be immediate from whatever definition you're using.

Comment: Ideal generated by x-1, y-1. oh ok. The coefficients can belong to K[x,y], right?

Comment: Well there you go.

Comment: I just want to make sure I get this right..The coefficients can belong to K[x,y] and that's why you used (x+1), right?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because the question is answered immediately by looking at the definition; it shows little to no effort at all.

Comment: Immediately for whom? For you? I just started learning this stuff, and I tried for quite a while before I posed this question. I did not realize that you could use non-constant coefficients to express $$y-x^2$$. Please demonstrate some empathy. There was surely a time when you were ignorant of all these things.

Comment: Indeed there was such a time. There is no need to take the downvote personally; it only reflects my opinion that this question is not up to the standards that I would like this website to keep meeting.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?